# SAS: Simple use of macros combined with a query

Tags: sas

I am trying to plug in all of the values in variable *name* for the following procedure.

```
data data00;
input name $;
cards;
Anna
Becca
Catherine
;
```

```
proc sql;
     select(x), count(x) from data00;
quit;
```

I want to basically plug in *Anna*, *Becca* and *Catherine*, but don't want to do it by hand because the real data I am using have 100s of these names.

I have been trying to figure out a way but anything that I look up is too complicated and I don't think that this procedure should be that difficult.

May I have some help, please?

Comment: What are you trying to plug `name` into? Currently your SQL statement will not select specific names, even if you plug them into `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you want generate and run these code:

```
proc sql;
   select(Anna), count(Anna) from data00;
   select(Becca), count(Becca) from data00;
   select(Catherine), count(Catherine) from data00;
quit;
```

I think what you are looking for is `call execute()`, try this:

```
data _null_;
  call execute('proc print data = sashelp.class; run;');
run;
```

Check the log and result window, you see `call execute()` can resolve strings as code and run it. So here comes your anwser:

```
data _null_;
  set data00 end=eof;
  if _n_ = 1 then call execute('proc sql;');
  call execute('select('||cats(name)||'), count('||cats(name)||') from data00;');
  if eof then call execute('quit;');
run;
```